# How can I get good spherification results with alcohol?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy, spherification

I've been trying to make chocolatini (vodka, godiva liqueur, baileys) spheres, but I've had some issues with separation of the alcohols.  Also, I've been deciding whether the alginate solution should be placed into the mixture (vs. calcium lactate into the mixture)... and then placed into calcium lactate solution or alginate solutions respectively.  Anybody have any suggestions or recipes for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

### Reverse spherification

You need to first make a sodium alginate bath, mix with one-third of the water to begin with using a hand blender and then add this to the final full proportions. You need to let this bath sit for a while to ensure there are no bubbles left. (Standard practice).

Add your calcium lactate to the mixture you are trying to spherify. Apparently thickening the the alcohol with xanthan gum can help to form better shaped spheres.

#### further information:

- http://blog.khymos.org/recipe-collection/ <-- fantastic recipe collection
- http://www.molecularrecipes.com/spherification/reverse-spherification/

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want to reverse your mix.The Godiva Liquer has natural calcium in it so therefor you want to reverse your mixture and add sodium alginate to your liquid and bath in the calcium lactate.

Comment: Lol, there is no calcium in godiva liqueur.